# Flask extract variables from a function python

Tags: python, html, function, flask

I created a form with flask using python and html.

I want to fill up a form and then save the values by clicking a Submit button in order to use them for another project.
But I also want to create another button which when I click on it fill automatically the form with default values (in my case, I want `0` everywhere).

Here is my HTML code `form.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample page to test fill_web_form.py</title>
</head>
<body>
<p1><strong>SAMPLE PAGE TO TEST FILL_WEB_FORM.PY</strong></p1>

<!--test form-->
<form method="post" action="/">
    Test the motor:<br>
    <table> 
        <tr> 
            <td> Function number: </td> 
            <td> <input type="text" name="functionnumber"> </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td> Angle: </td> 
            <td> <input type="text" name="angle"> </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td> Speed: </td> 
            <td> <input type="text" name="speed"> </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td> <input type="submit" name="btn" Value="Submit"> </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td> <input type="submit" name="btn" Value="TURNON"> </td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And my python code `hello.py`:

```
# sends data from html form to database
from flask import Flask 
from flask import request 
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def form():
    return render_template('form.html') 

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def get_parameters():
    if request.form["btn"] == "Submit":
        form_params = []
        form_params.append(request.form['functionnumber'])
        form_params.append(request.form['angle'])
        form_params.append(request.form['speed'])       
    else:
        form_params = []
        form_params.append('0')
        form_params.append('0')
        form_params.append('0')
    return render_template('form.html'), str(form_params)

get_parameters()
print(get_parameters.form_params[0])
```

The two last lines are when I am trying to extract the variables from the function because I need to use them (I haven't implemented yet the code about why I need these variables). I am printing the value of `functionnumber` --> `print(get_parameters.form_params[0])` in order to see of it's working well.

Unfortunately I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Camille\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Camille\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Camille\Documents\myproject\venv\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\camille\documents\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 990, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:])
  File "c:\users\camille\documents\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 596, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\camille\documents\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1062, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\camille\documents\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1668, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\users\camille\documents\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\camille\documents\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 763, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\camille\documents\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\camille\documents\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 763, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\camille\documents\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 845, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "c:\users\camille\documents\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 321, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "c:\users\camille\documents\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 346, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "c:\users\camille\documents\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 402, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "c:\users\camille\documents\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 256, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Camille\Documents\myproject\hello.py", line 25, in <module>
    get_parameters()
  File "C:\Users\Camille\Documents\myproject\hello.py", line 13, in get_parameters
    if request.form["btn"] == "Submit":
  File "c:\users\camille\documents\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 422, in __get__
    obj = instance._get_current_object()
  File "c:\users\camille\documents\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 544, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()  # type: ignore
  File "c:\users\camille\documents\myproject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 33, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

When I don't add the two last line, it's working but it's still an issue because I can't use and extract the variables.
I want to access the variables `form_params[0]`, `form_params[1]`, `form_params[2]` outside the function.

Comment: depending on what you are trying to make, you would have to store the data in a database, or for a PoC, store it in a global variable and access it in another function. In your code, you are calling `get_parameters()` which is meant to be triggered via a HTTP request hence the error

Comment: With a global variable, my http status is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has 2 parts:

1. How to add default values to HTML input fields:
   You can either give default value by default rather than on a button click, this way:

```
<input type="text" name="speed" value="0">
```

I'm not sure why you want it to appear on a button click. But if you really want it that way you need to add some JavaScript and do it, something like this:

**HTML**

```
<form id="form">
<input type="text" name="speed">
<input type="text" name="angle">
<form>
<button id="btn"> Add default values </button>
```

**JS** (with jQuery)

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
  $("#form")
    .find("input")
    .each(function (i) {
      $(this).attr("value", "0");
    });
});
```

2. Run your flask server and just use the Browser or Postman to call your route and see what it returns.

Comment: You can test it here: https://codepen.io/sumant-agnihotri/pen/gOWXrzj